# UIImage drawAtPoint after CGContextClip

Tags: iphone, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I use ABUITableViewCell and draw all content manually. Also I use CGContextClip to make rounded corners, all works great, but when I tried to draw another image outside clip rect it hasn't been displayed.

When I draw NSString I use CGContextSaveGState(context) function and text will be shown. But the image is not.

How to draw image after CGContextClip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the state and then make sure you restore it afterward. Just draw the image after the `CGContextRestoreGState`.

If that's already what you're describing, then you may just be drawing the image in the wrong place.

You should make sure all save state calls you make are balanced by restores.

Comment: My code do following steps: http://pastebin.com/AkbRtSj0    thanks for the reply!

Comment: You need another save before your clip and after you should restore after you draw the image in the clipped area.